# Assignment of dynamic class type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a dictionary that contains a Class string name as the key and an array of corresponding class objects as the value.

It could be a number of different Class types that come in, so I wanted to do dynamic assignment at runtime.

Does anyone know why this code gives a compiler error?

```
// Where obj is an object of type MyClass
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
myClass *objectOfTypeMyClass = obj;
```

Update:

Here's how i ended up implementing it:

```
Class interestClass = NSClassFromString(classProvidedAsString);
id interest = [interestClass createNewInterestUsingManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
[interest setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
[interest addLikedByObject:aFriend];
```

Where title is a property on all objects that I can accept, and createNewInterest is a method all objects have.

The problem was trying to cast id as interestClass to use the properties and methods of that class.

Comment: What you want is not possible. `NSStringFromClass()` is a function that will be evaluated at runtime - you want the information available at compile time. If all the objects respond to the same methods then you could potentially use a `protocol` to achieve this

Comment: I used id and a protocol to ensure they all responded to a certain message. I used Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass"); to instantiate it, and kvc to set the properties. All good, thanks!

Comment: You used a `protocol` and `KVC`? if you used a protocol then `KVC` is not required and by using it you lose the compiler checking benefit of using a `protocol`, so you may as well not use the `protocol`.

Comment: I used KVC to set the properties of the id obj.

Answer (score 2):

Why just don't you use `id`?

```
id objectOfTypeMyClass = obj;
```

Another option would be use polymorphism (if the classes were created by you).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
NSObject *object=[NSObject new];//this can hold any kind of object

object=@"my name is lakhan";//as string
NSLog(@"%@",object);

object=@[@(10),@(50)]; //now working as array
NSLog(@"%@",object);

object=@{@"k1": @"10", @"k2":@"20"}; // as dictionary
NSLog(@"%@",object);
```

So as per your requirement you can use whatever value you need to set on the object.

Comment: Any technical reason why you've preferred `NSObject *` over `id`?

Comment: OK, but I want to use NSStringFromClass so I can typecast my id obj and have the properties and methods available to it. Is this possible?

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin: NSStringFromClass will give you only you string. from that string you can't form an object. But from that string you can conditionaly for any kind of object. as in my answer, i formed string, array, dictionary.

Comment: See comment above for how i solved this. Thank you for pointing out id, as it was instrumental in my implementation!

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin: I cant see anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, NSClassFromString :) @Anoop it's in the comments section of my post

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin You should post an answer instead of updating the question. It might confuse visitors to this post.